# Looking for a way to do an app translation of ORA error messages

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working on an app with many pages and a lot of interconnectivity between tables. And I want a custom message to display(or change text of error message) when a user attempts to delete a record with a child.
Basically, when a user gets the following error:
'Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - ORA-02292: integrity constraint (FRAPIS.AZK_KPN_FK) violated - child record found - 
Contact your application administrator.'
I want them to see something else, that tells them they cannot delete this record untill they delete all child records.
I know the error already basically says this, but this is for end users, and some might not even know english(the app is translated).

I have tried setting a dynamic translation, but it did nothing(only translates my plsql values).
I have tried searching for a full list of text messages so I could add a translation, but no luck so far. Best I got was on http://translate-apex.com/ which I had already used to translate the rest of the app, but it didnt contain any translations for the server errors

I did find some people talking about capturing the error and something, but its from 2008, for APEX 5 and I have no idea what exactly they mean:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/681328

I know I could get this done with custom validations, but that would require a LOT of code to do this one thing. And I dont want to go that route(this isnt essential, users can probably understand what the error means). I am looking for a method that translates this for the entire application, or at least a method that works on one page and just needs to be copied over to other pages with minimal or perhaps even no modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into it and found a solution.

In Shared Components- Application Definition Attributes you can set an Error handling function. Which can do many things, amongst them is to change the message into whatever you want.

http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2018/06/automatically-capture-all-errors-and.html

This link has some instructions on how to do it and I managed to get it working.